# float representing hours to hours:minutes:seconds using c#

Tags: c#, double, timespan

I need to convert a float representing hours to Hours:Minutes:Seconds.

How is that possible by using C#.

Currently i am converting this 5.4898391027272906 float hour to Hours minutes and seconds, i got a desire results for only till hours and minutes but not for seconds.

Below is my code:

```
double time = 5.4898391027272906;
double hours = Math.Floor(time);
double minutes = Math.Floor(time * 60 % 60);
double seconds = Math.Floor(time * 360 % 360);
```

> Result: hours = 5, minutes = 29 and seconds = 176

but i want to get a seconds in between 60 seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure that putting a time in a `float` is completely reversible, even with a *second* resolution. And that number seems to be a `double`, not a `float` (too many decimals)

Comment: yes @xanatos it is double not float, i mistakenly write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using [`TimeSpan.FromHours`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx) method?

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(5.4898391027272906);
Console.WriteLine(ts.Seconds); // 23
```

Don't use some integer calculations for time intervals. This is *exactly* what [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.aspx) is for.

By the way, you code won't even compile. Without any suffix, your `5.4898391027272906` will be `double` not `float` and there is no implicit conversation from `double` to `float`. You need to use `f` or `F` suffix. And this `TimeSpan.FromHours` method takes `double` as a parameter, not `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Your original method wouldn't work because there are 3600 seconds in an hour, not 360, and because using modulo like that doesn't work anyway!  You could get the seconds from the minutes, e.g. 29.39 minutes * 60 % 60 = 23.4 seconds.